# StrongLoop Loopback - Error: Cannot find module 'on-finished'

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm having a blocking issue with StrongLoop Loopback. I just started having the following error when I tried to start up my API...

James-MacBook-Pro:rti_loopback_api jameseisenlohr$ node .
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

```
Error: Cannot find module 'on-finished'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jameseisenlohr/Google Drive/Sites/rti_loopback_api/node_modules/express/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js:16:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
```

James-MacBook-Pro:rti_loopback_api jameseisenlohr$

Any thoughts? I am stumped. I defined no model named 'no-finished'. I have no clue where to look to resolve this error.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
James

Comment: What version of node are you using? Have you tried reinstalling (npm install -g strongloop) and running `slc loopback` again? What OS are you on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you run `npm install` in your project?
If you did that and error still exists, try installing that module : `npm install on-finished --save`

Comment: I did run an npm install and that did not correct the issue. I recreated the entire project in loopback version 3.x and did not run npm install on-finished --save ... now I am receiving an error for a different missing module.

Comment: @JamesEisenlohr So accept this answer and make a new issue. And for new issue please provide the error completely

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information regarding your mac environment as well
as reproducible steps, This will allow us to reproduce your issues.

You can enter the following in your terminal.

```
 which node
 which npm
 npm ls -g  strongloop
```

1.Which version of node.js and npm and where is it installed?
2.You loopback project is under google-drive ,is node.js npm and strongloop also
under google-drive or somewhere else?
3.How did you create your loopback project?

when you perform slc loopback - what did you enter ?

```
 What kind of application do you have in mind? empty-server (An empty LoopBack API, without any configured models or dataso
urces)
? Which version of LoopBack would you like to use? 3.x or 2.x
```

4.You defined no model named 'no-finished'.<== Can you please elaborate?
Did you do a slc loopback:model?

If you can attach your generated project , it will be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: James-MacBook-Pro:rti_loopback_new jameseisenlohr$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node
James-MacBook-Pro:rti_loopback_new jameseisenlohr$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node
James-MacBook-Pro:rti_loopback_new jameseisenlohr$  which npm
/usr/local/bin/npm
James-MacBook-Pro:rti_loopback_new jameseisenlohr$  npm ls -g  strongloop
/usr/local/lib
└── strongloop@6.0.1

Comment: No, I did not do an slc loopback:model... I have no idea what the no-finished module was?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure strongloop is installed.
Use the following command:

`npm install -g strongloop --msvs_version=2012`